# No module named pycurl [Python]

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion

I tried to run python script with my mac os x lion mountain I installed MacPorts & Command line for Xcode .. also I installed py27-yaml & py27-curl

and the first line for the python script is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

because I typed which python in Terminal and show for me the directory like above

so what is the problem ? it show this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/auto.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pycurl
ImportError: No module named pycurl
```

Thanks alot ..